# Call COM exe API from NSIS script

Tags: c++, nsis

Is it possible to call an api exposed in COM exe server from NSIS script?
I am not able to find any documentation for that. If anyone knows , please reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic syntax looks like:

```
System::Call "$0->2()"
```

where $0 is the COM object and 2 is the 0 based index of the method in the vtable (2 is Release)

http://nsis.sourceforge.net/System_plug-in_readme#Usage_Examples_2